# Printing ReportBuilder Reports to Excel in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, reportbuilder

We used to use ExtraDevices to print ReportBuilder Reports to Excel.  Unfortunately, there seems to be no support for Delphi XE.

Can someone suggest an alternative way to print a ReportBuidler Report to Excel?  It doesn't have to be a free solution, though an open source option is always preferable.

I am currently considering [Gnostice](http://www.gnostice.com/eDocEngine_VCL.asp) and [ReportBuilder Export Devices Pro](http://www.rarefind.com/rbpro/features.html)

Our only requirement is to be able to print to Excel, so my initial sense is that option 2 might be a better fit.

How reliable are these tools?  And, can someone suggest other alternatives?  We do not need to print to PDF.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe that in the latest version of reportbuilder (16.0), you can export a report to the xlsx format.

Comment: @Copilot, thanks for that info.  I would very quickly buy the latest version of RPB.  Unfortunately, we are stuck at Delphi XE, and RPB 16 won't work with XE.

Comment: Has anyone ever contacted RareFind, the maker of RPB Export Devices Pro?  There are issues with his downloads.  I sent a couple of emails, but no Response.

Comment: on the official website I find information that RB16 does support Delphi XE, maybe you should contact them to confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late now but I am leaving this response for anyone else who might be interested in it. (I am from Gnostice.) If you are using eDocEngine, there are three ways to save the report as XLS. Instead of the PDF engine component used in this article, use our XLS engine component. You can enable the print to file option and let it save to an XLS file. You can also use a RTM template, load it with data and print to file. You can also create a RAF file and also render it to XLS without any user interaction.
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=243&t=Export_From_ReportBuilder_To_PDF_And_Other_Formats